# Android AdMob: The import com.google.ads cannot be resolved

Tags: android, api, admob, adview

I've done this steps:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals
- but it doesn't work.
In my app's class I put: "import com.google.ads.*" and the Eclipse gives me an error: "The import com.google.ads cannot be resolved."

In the manifest file I put:
    
    ...

In: Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries I've added "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar".
I checked in: Properties > Android > Google APIs

What I do wrong?

Comment: In `Java Build Path -> Order and Export`, is the `jar` file checked off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there aren't any other compilation errors,
Remove and re-add the Jar file and clean and rebuild.

Comment: thanks! It worked! :)) I remove the Jar file and added it again - and now it works! :)